# How to minimise the search time in Objective-C

Tags: ios, sorting, search

I am Implementing a search in a `JSON` data which contains data in `HTML` format.

Problem is that the Data is very big.

And I have to show the matched Searches in Color as shown In Image:

For example I searched for `How`:

[image]

My Searching Flow is Like that:

Step 1: - Check for presence of Data

Step 2: - Strip Html Tags from Searching Content

Step 3: - Perform Search In Content
          using NSRange rangeOfString options

Step 4: - If Match Found. Break Content in Sentence By using 
          componentSeparatedByString 
          (as I have to show the sentence in which i have found the search)

Step 5: - Pass the Sentence in Function which is returning me the
          Attributed String

Step 6: - Add Results In array and reload the table

I am performing the search result in `TextField` Delegate method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`

The problem is I am getting my table in delay of 1 to 2 sec.

And if type to fast then Suppose I search for `Animal` then I get search for `ani` `anim` and at last `animal`.

How Can I enhance my searching.

Comment: A question of this nature may be better served at http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks @rmaddy for your suggestion :)

Comment: First of all, there is no need to break the string. Just create an attributed string from the whole thing and just add attributes for given ranges. You might also consider doing debouncing (e.g. in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` start a timer which will update highlighting after 0.1 sec and if there is another change between that 0.1 elapses, just cancel the timer and plan new update after 0.1). That's a common fix for too many updates when typing too fast.

Comment: If I do this then How can the sentence i which the search word is detected? I done this before but this doesn't work

Comment: Hmm, I see. If you are searching only for sentences, maybe you should mantain your data as an array of sentences? Then you could search using a simple `NSPredicate`.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is the following:

**Preparation**

Steps 1 and 2. Don't repeat them for every search, do them once before starting to search or during only the first search.

Additional Step: Split the text into sentences. You will have a `NSArray` of sentences as your input.

**Search**

Use the search text to build a `NSPredicate` (e.g. `contains[cd]`). Filter the input array using that predicate. That should be very fast.

Reload the table to display results. Don't bother with attributed strings here.

**Highlighting**

Highlight using the current search text when displaying the cell (generate an attributed string). You will highlight only what is actually displayed so this should be very fast.

**Possible improvements**

Debouncing - Don't start searching immediately after search text changes. Start a timer which will search in 0.1-0.5 seconds. If there is a new search text update sooner, cancel the previous timer and start a new one. This will merge several updates into one updates.

Use previous search result - if the previous search text is a substring of the new search text, you can search only the previous results, that is, less data to search.

If the search is still too slow (if you really have an enormous amount of text), perform the search in a different dispatch queue and show an activity indicator until the results are done.

Comment: thanks a lot... I am changing my implementation as guided by you.. I will surley get back to you if their is any issues or improvements